# No mobile broadband connection on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: wireless, networking, internet, broadband

I installed ubuntu 11.10 and from start I have no mobile broadband in my network indicator.

It used to work form live CD but when I installed it, mobile broadband wasn't listed at all.

When I plug in my 3g USB modem stick I get in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Mar 12 21:08:12 goran-home-ubuntu kernel: [ 1349.648137] usb 2-4: new high speed USB device number 13 using ehci_hcd
Mar 12 21:08:12 goran-home-ubuntu mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 13: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-4"
Mar 12 21:08:12 goran-home-ubuntu kernel: [ 1349.786894] scsi16 : usb-storage 2-4:1.0
Mar 12 21:08:13 goran-home-ubuntu mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 13 was not an MTP device
Mar 12 21:08:13 goran-home-ubuntu usb_modeswitch: switching 1bbb:f000 (USBModem: HSPA Data Card)
Mar 12 21:08:14 goran-home-ubuntu kernel: [ 1351.025293] usb 2-4: USB disconnect, device number 13
Mar 12 21:08:14 goran-home-ubuntu kernel: [ 1351.392152] usb 2-4: new high speed USB device number 14 using ehci_hcd
Mar 12 21:08:14 goran-home-ubuntu mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 14: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-4"
Mar 12 21:08:14 goran-home-ubuntu mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 14 was not an MTP device
Mar 12 21:08:14 goran-home-ubuntu kernel: [ 1351.536138] option 2-4:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Mar 12 21:08:14 goran-home-ubuntu kernel: [ 1351.536280] usb 2-4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Mar 12 21:08:14 goran-home-ubuntu kernel: [ 1351.536412] option 2-4:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Mar 12 21:08:14 goran-home-ubuntu kernel: [ 1351.536503] usb 2-4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
Mar 12 21:08:14 goran-home-ubuntu kernel: [ 1351.536932] scsi17 : usb-storage 2-4:1.2
Mar 12 21:08:14 goran-home-ubuntu kernel: [ 1351.537215] option 2-4:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Mar 12 21:08:14 goran-home-ubuntu kernel: [ 1351.537350] usb 2-4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
Mar 12 21:08:14 goran-home-ubuntu usb_modeswitch: switched to 1bbb:0000 (USBModem: HSPA Data Card)
Mar 12 21:08:15 goran-home-ubuntu usb_modeswitch[32008]: usb_modeswitch: adding device ID 1bbb:0000 to driver option
Mar 12 21:08:15 goran-home-ubuntu kernel: [ 1352.538247] scsi 17:0:0:0: Direct-Access     USBModem MMC Storage      2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Mar 12 21:08:15 goran-home-ubuntu kernel: [ 1352.564799] sd 17:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Mar 12 21:08:15 goran-home-ubuntu kernel: [ 1352.571989] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

It looks like USB modem is ready (I get flashing green light) but nothing happens.

I don't know if this is related but, in my network settings airplane mode to alway ON and I can't even switch wireless ON and airplane mod to OFF. Note also that there is no mobile broadband option in network settings.

[image]

When I run `lsusb` I get this:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b128 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 016: ID 1bbb:0000 T & A Mobile Phones 
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 0930:020f Toshiba Corp.
```

**EDIT: I use [ALCATEL X080S](http://www.alcatelonetouch.com/global-en/products/mobile_broadband/ot-x080.html) 3g USB modem stick.**

Comment: Can you add what kind of mobile dongle it is?

Comment: I am also having same problem with my Nokia x2-00 I was unable to connect to internet with Ubuntu. Till 11/03/12 I was able to connect my another Nokia phone 3500c with Docomo sim to Ubuntu 11.10 64bit . It was working nice. Internet connection was attached in few seconds. But on 12/03/12 when I was trying to update my Ubuntu 11.10 some update came and asked to restart my computer. when I restarted Ubuntu then my Nokia 3500c was also not able to connect to internet as mobile broadband was disabled this time.

Comment: @JorgeCastro I updated my question, I put link to my modem spec at the end.

Comment: @JorgeCastro I really don't think it is related to modem model, I have seen lots of similar questions here with all kinds of modems and no valid answers :(

Comment: How can I change my connection from 2G to 3G without disconnecting in ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with that ALCATEL modem, with new release of ubuntu (12.04) it all works as expected. So I suggest upgrade for anyone who have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

could you please check on network icon in system tray left of volume icon. click there you will see edit connection. click on that you will find Mobile Broadband. then "add".

Sorry in advance if I do mistake. I'm not expert in Linux.[image]

Comment: @Kazweb I have had configuration set up there, and I had it set up right, problem was with that ALCATEL modem, as soon as I upgraded to 12.04 it all worked as expected.