# Is the Lenovo Ideapad Z570 fully compatible with 12.04?

Tags: lenovo, compatibility, ideapad

I'm looking for some notebook that will run on Ubuntu perfectly. I like LENOVO IdeaPad Z570, but I'm not sure how it will perform on Ubuntu.

I heard people are complaining about [wireless problems](https://www.google.com/search?aq=f&ix=aca&sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=LENOVO%20IdeaPad%20Z570%20ubuntu).

Here is [full configuraion](http://www.computers.rs/18611/lenovo-ideapad-z570-59316593-15.6-intel-core-i5-2430m-4gb-750gb-nvidia-geforce-gt520.html):

```
 Processor  Intel Core i5 2430M 2.4GHz - 3.0GHz
Chipset Intel HM65 Express
Memory  4GB DDR3 1333MHz
Graphics    NVIDIA GeForce GT 520M 1GB
HDD 750GB SATA II
Wireless 802.11b/g/n, Bluetooth 2.1
Network adapter Ethernet LAN 10/100Mbps
Ports VGA, HDMI, 3x USB 2.0, eSATA
```

Does anyone have experience with this model? Any problems noted?

I heard there is a [test suite](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/test-suite/), how can I install it? Maybe I can boot live CD and try it myself before buying it. But, [unfortunately](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112402/no-mobile-broadband-connection-on-ubuntu-11-10), sometimes something works on live CD, but not when you install it.

I guess critical components here are graphics and wireless.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: The Lenovo Thinkpad T-series runs *perfectly* with Ubuntu. Backed up with personal experience over the years, as well as others on AU chatroom.

Comment: They cost more :) What is AU chatroom? Thanks.

Comment: Join us: fun and expert recommendations ;) 
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room

Comment: Also keep an eye on kernel 3.6 :) atm the -rc2 version already has an z570 support for fan control button and other super things patched :) Just to mention :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have Lenovo Ideapad Z570 (59-326321). I've tried Ubuntu 12.04 (both LiveCD and installation).

Had to manually install Bumblebee for Nvidia GPU to work.

Everything else works fine right from the box.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How did you install that, is there a package? What if you don't install it? Did you like how Lenovo works?

Comment: I've used this guide: http://geek.co.il/wp/2012/02/19/nvidia-optimus-on-ubuntu-12-04
without updating from xorg-edgers ppa

Comment: If you don't install Bumblebee you wouldn't be able to run harware accelerated 3D applications with acceptable speed.
The device is little heavier then I anticipated and has a warm bottom. So if you want to hold it on your laps I'm suggesting to go for a lighter model with a smaller screen size.

Comment: That can be fixed with some cooler stand. Is keyboard hot? Thanks.

Comment: It isn't. Keyboard is not even warm to the touch.

Comment: Whats your experience with Bumblebee - Is it good or just fine ? While playing games etc ?

Answer (score 1):

I use the ubuntu partition in very rare ocassions, ive tried 11.10 and 12.04 and in both versions the nvidia card doesnt work (and when you have 1GB, you will want to use it)

I tried installing the driver manually and using bumblebee but this last one just turned off the card. So my solution is using windows7 for my 3dmax and gaming.

I recommend not buying a notebook that uses an nvidia optimus card. There is no support.